# Angular 2 Typescript Push Array Inside Object

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to push an array into my object and Angular seems to just refuse to let it happen and I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Here is my "Job" that contains multiple transactions and my transaction class.

```
export class Job {
  Id: number;
  transactions: Transaction[];
}

export class Transaction {
  transactionId: number;
  transactionTime: Date;
}
```

In my component I declare a new empty Job like...  and then after the user enters some data and does a button onclick I wanted to just add myTransaction to myJob doing something like this...

```
myjob = new Job();
myTransaction = new Transaction();

this.myjob.transactions.push(this.myTransaction);
```

This doesnt give an error but when I do the onlick event the page acts like it is doing a post and then something happens.

Am I messing up the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't posted your template, but I'm assuming that you're using a button. You must set the `type=button` otherwise it will submit the form.

Comment: It cannot easily post my template but I have found when I comment out the  `this.myjob.transactions.push(this.myTransaction);` it is not doing the page reload thing.  I believe its only doing that because the push is not working.

Comment: From your code you have so far `this.myjob.transactions` is undefined. You should initialize the array in your class like so `transactions: Transaction[] = [];`. Also check the console for an error.

Comment: @andreim Thank you! The issue ended up me not initializing my array in my class when I changed it to `transactions: Transaction[] = [];` it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to declare transactions just as an array like that :

```
transactions: Transaction[] = [];
```